# How to create an Online Dictionary Using WordPress?

Tags: directory

I want to make an online dictionary for Hebrew and English, and also want to use it in WordPress. Is this possible? (Especially using the free version?)

Comment: There's only one version of WordPress and it's free. There's no version that should cost you money.

Comment: @Pete That's not true, because not everyone can host it. Lost of people mean "paying already hosted Wordpress" when they talk about "Wordpress".